# What is the Equivalent of the c++ AnsiString in c#?

Tags: c#, c++builder

I am trying to convert a c++ code to c#. I have only 10% knowledge in c++. And this is the part of the code that i am trying to convert in c#
"`AnsiString something[200];`" and. 
 "`AnsiString hi = "hello";`".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless you intend to pass ansi strings to native code why not just convert it to `string`?  c# is unicode and generally the only time you need to worry about ansi strings is with native code

Comment: There is no `AnsiString` in standard C++.    I assume you're referring to the `AnsiString` provided with C++ Builder - a particular vendor's product.   If so, tag your question accordingly - you'll have more chance then of getting useful replies.

Comment: i don't know c++ that much but can u explain ur motive so that i can help ?

Comment: @S.M.   - If I'm reading right, the `AnsiString` is a non-standard type provided by C++ Builder (a vendor-specific development environment).   It is not related to the meaning of ANSI character encoding.

Comment: @S.M.  It appears I was correct, since the OP has removed the C++ tag, and re-tagged C++Builder.

Comment: Strings in C# are always Unicode, encoded in utf16.  There is no option to use legacy 8-bit encoded strings other than in I/O, like the Encoding you can pass to a StreamReader.  Simply use `string` here.

Comment: @HansPassant: while that is true, that is generally no problem. If an AnsiString is used as intended in C++Builder (i.e. to contain text), the code can easily be converted to C# and 16 bit (UTF-16) strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AnsiString` in C++ Builder is a reference-counted, copy-on-write, 8-bit string. Suitable type in C# is `string` or `System.String` for 16-bit Unicode.

### C++ Builder

```
AnsiString something[200];
AnsiString hi = "hello";
```

---

### C#

```
string[] something = new string[200];
string hi = "hello";
```

Comment: So how do i use this "AnsiString something[200];" in c#?

Comment: Thanks. That's an accurate answer.